# C# Manipular resposta do PostAsync

Tags: c#, json, .net, api

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
        string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
        {
            email = textBoxLogin.Text,
            password = textBoxSenha.Text
        });

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = client.PostAsync(
                "https://apidomeuservidor.site/estabelecimento/auth/entrar",
                 new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            var resposta = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            MessageBox.Show(resposta.ToString());
        }
```

A resposta desta chamada é assim:

```
"data": {
        "access_token": "TOKEN QUE QUERO yvOujoe7bOh5eypOZiPQ9dXrxR-XbE",
        "token_type": "bearer",
        "expires_in": 2592000
    }
```

**Como eu faço para manipular esta resposta?**

A resposta da API está sendo 200, só que não consigo manipular a resposta

Eu consigo pegar o código Status e outras coisas, mas resposta mesmo não consigo

Obrigado desde já

Comment: O que vc quer dizer por manipular? Vc quer "transformar" a resposta do seu request em um objeto, para usá-lo?

Comment: Isto para usar no código - sendo object, list, array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui de um jeito simples:

...

```
var response = client.PostAsync(
                    "https://apilink.site/estabelecimento/auth/entrar",
                     new StringContent(jsonEnvio, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

var jsonResposta = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
MessageBox.Show(jsonResposta.ToString());

dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResposta);
MessageBox.Show(data.data.access_token.ToString());
```

Achei bem simples assim!

Answer (score 2):

Instale o pacote nuget `FakeItEasy`, crie um `fake` do `HttpClient`.

Um exemplo simples seria algo assim:

```
private HttpClient CreateFakeHttpClient()
{
    var fakeHttpClient = A.Fake<HttpClient>(options => options.CallsBaseMethods());
    A.CallTo(() => fakeHttpClient.SendAsync(A<HttpRequestMessage>._, A<CancellationToken>._)).ReturnsLazily((HttpRequestMessage a, CancellationToken b) => CustomSendAsync(fakeHttpClient, a, b));
    return fakeHttpClient;
}

private Task<HttpResponseMessage> CustomSendAsync(HttpClient customClient, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    string json = @"""data"": {
                    ""access_token"": ""TOKEN QUE QUERO"",
                    ""token_type"": ""bearer"",
                    ""expires_in"": 2592000
                    }";

    return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
    });
}
```

Depois é só testar chamando o método `CreateFakeHttpClient`.
Claro que isso é de forma bem simplória, é possível elaborar algo bem mais sofisticado... Mas dessa forma já deve funcionar.

Answer (score 2):

Para utilizar a resposta de um request como objeto é necessário "deserializar" o corpo da resposta. A biblioteca mais utilizada para isso é o Newtonsoft (ou Json.NET). Inclua essa lib no seu projeto e faça `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SuaClasse>(jsonString)`, onde `SuaClasse` é uma classe que vc precisa criar no seu projeto.

```cs
var resposta = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var objetoResposta = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SuaClasse>(resposta);
```

Comment: Como a resposta (da API) em alguns casos serão variados usando um dynamic facilita mais ainda. Obrigado pela reposta